# Xcode Main.storyboard not showing what appears in the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, storyboard

I am working on a project with other teammates so we have be storing our project on the cloud as a zip file.  After unzipping the file, Xcode does not display the main.storyboard correctly; won't show buttons, labels, images, etc. However, when built using the simulator, all of these display correctly.  In Xcode I can access them and change them but am unable to delete or move them through the main.storyboard.  Any ideas or suggestions to fix this inconvenience?

Comment: Please, provide a screenshot of the `storyboard` that u can see

Comment: Do you use Size Classes? Maybe you don't have any elements for current settings?

Comment: I can't add images because I am new to the site. Have used it for answers before but can't seem to fix this issue from previously asked questions. I may just start that specific UIViewController from scratch.  Thanks for trying to help anyways.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? I'm having the same problem too in Xcode 7

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the view controller is locked to prevent editing. Try unlocking it by

Select `Identity Inspector` of view and set `Lock` to `Nothing`
[image]